# How do I blend X frames to one frame to get motion blur?

Tags: swift, cocoa, image-processing, motion-blur

I want to blend a bunch (let's say… about 40) of frames together to get one motion blurred frame. As of now, my application just draws all the frames on top of the first one at 10% opacity, but that doesn't look convincing enough for me.

How do Premiere Pro or current game engines do motion blur? The frames I work with are being rendered offline, so render speed (or lack thereof) isn't an issue. I'd appreciate help and/or examples of proper frame blending done programmatically.

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. Try to provide pictures what you have and what you're trying to achieve, not demo video. Provide more context, are you developing 3D game, what kind of technology do you use, what do you mean under 'frame'?

Comment: What I'm developing is utterly irrelevant. What matters is that I have a set amount of frames (or 'video frames' for the uninitiated) that I need to blend together in order to mimic the kind of motion blur that's present in all footage recorded by video cameras. Why did you even bother writing an answer to my question if you have no idea what I'm talking about?

Comment: Read the following article http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Good luck.

Comment: You being unable to understand what I'm talking about does not magically make my question unclear. Frame blending is not a new concept, it's what literally _every_ 3D movie studio in the last 20+ years has used to do realistic motion blur. This video https://youtu.be/w4wse6_9oEM?t=2m28s is the second Google result when searching for "frame blending". There is **no** excuse for answering a question with irrelevant nonsense, then going "I think the question is unclear, it's not my fault my answer is irrelevant".

Comment: For some reasons my irrelevant answer was up voted twice. I repeat, you should improve your question, now it's a bit low quality. Also http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: The fact that your answer was upvoted means nothing. I've seen answers that were plain wrong and yet had more upvotes than the correct, accepted answer. On SO, nothing surprises me anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Cocoa Core Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185)? It's a really powerful framework for your purposes.
All you need is to apply simple filter to the image (in your case is frame).
Take a look at the snippet code from [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-TPXREF101):

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];
[filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:@0.8f forKey:kCIInputIntensityKey];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CGRect extent = [result extent];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:extent];
```

Just set the filter name to `CIMotionBlur` ([Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBoxBlur)) and set its values.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to help, but please actually read the question next time. The first sentence is "I want to blend a bunch […] of frames together to get one motion blurred frame". I don't want to blindly apply motion blur in random directions, I want to use frame blending to get more natural looking motion blur.

Comment: @PeterW. can you please provide picture you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x27hwqP_w4k This motion blur effect is achieved by first rendering out all frames in slow motion, then blending them together to get one real time frame. It's kinda hard to explain with words.